# Limit the Number of Simultaneously Running Threads

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I have a script that does a ping sweep on my work environment and I am trying to limit the number of simultaneously running threads. I have been playing around with many of the solutions online but I cant seem to make any progress. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$scriptblock = {

Param($comp)
IF (Test-Connection -computername $comp -Quiet -Count 1) {
    [bool]$responding = $true
}
else {
    Write-Host "***$comp ERROR -Not responding***" 
    $responding = $false
}

New-Object psobject -Property @{'Computer Name' = $comp;
    'Online'                        = $responding;

}  

}

$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$CurrentDate = $CurrentDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss')
$location = Get-Location

$comps = (get-content -path $location'\hostnames.txt').Trim()
$comps | ForEach-Object {Start-Job -Scriptblock $scriptblock -ArgumentList  $_ | Out-Null}

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job | Select-Object 'Computer Name','Online'`
-ExcludeProperty RunspaceId, PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName   |   Export-csv -NoTypeInformation "$location\PingTest-$CurrentDate.csv"
```

Comment: the `Test-Connection` cmdlet has a `-ThrottleLimit` parameter. i have not tested it, but that _looks_ like it would do what you want.

Comment: Hi Lee_Dailey, I don't think that will accomplish what I am trying to do but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: ah! [*grin*] well, in that case you may want to look as the PoshRSJob module. it has a `-ThrottleLimit` parameter for the `Start-RSJob` cmdlet.